# Java - Copy long text of a text file to another

Tags: java

I have one txt file with a very, very long text and I want to read, make some changes and copy that text to other txt files. The problem is that I can't read the file by the `BufferedReader` because I'd have to store the text in a variable, but that can't be done due to capacity and then write it to another file... Is there a way this can be done?

Comment: How long is the text file?

Comment: Read it in chucks [`BufferedReader#read(char[] cbuf, int off, int len)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read(char[],%20int,%20int)) or use the NIO2 API, [Copying a File or Directory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/copy.html). Personally, I'd prefer to use a `InputStream` for file copying

Comment: Or stream it from the `InputStream` to the `OutputStream` one `byte` at a time.

Comment: Do you want to copy _all_ the contents or only a part of it? If all the contents there is no reason to go through a `Reader` to start with.

Comment: all, maybe I have a wrong way with `BufferedReader` but I need to make some changes first, convert all `a` to `b` let's say

Comment: This wasn't in your original question... Edit the question and be more precise.

Comment: If your file is data and it is getting that big (bigger than 1/2 a gig heuristically) you probably want to store it in a database, not a txt file.

Comment: [Memory mapped file](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/01/memorymapped-file-and-io-in-java.html) ?

Comment: Why do you have to store large data in variable?

Comment: To make some replaces in text and then let's say writer:write(data) imo =|

Answer (score 0):

BuffereReader(Writer) works fine for this tasks (reading,writing large files)

```
        BufferedWriter bw=null ;
        BufferedReader br=null;
        try{    
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("e:/temp/1.txt")));
            bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("e:/temp/2.txt")));
            String st="";
            while((st=br.readLine())!=null){


                bw.write(st.replace("a","b"));
                bw.newLine();

            }
            bw.close();
            br.close();

        }catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }finally
        {   


        }
```